# Silverlight: Web does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, http, silverlight

I am a beginner in `Silverlight` and I am trying to create a `web application` that can connect to a `database` using their `APIs`. However, the connection to their API requires a reference to `System.Web` in my `viewmodel class`.

How can I add this reference to my `Silverlight` application? When I try to install `ASP.NET Web API 2.2`, I get the error

> the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference you are trying to add is to the Web API component of the ASP.NET framework ([details](http://www.asp.net/web-api)), which enables you to author an API and host it in ASP.NET. This is not what you want, and not compatible with Silverlight.

Unfortunately, Silverlight does not provide the full set of .NET functionality and libraries (as it's a lightweight, web version). You can see the full namespace availability [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194(v=vs.95).aspx), `System.Web` is not included.